# How can I find all records where $type of field not equal 'date'?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want get all records from collection, there deleted is not true, and $type of 'startDate' or 'endDate' is not 'date'. I am trying to use this find query:

```
{
        '$and' :
            {
                {'deleted' : {'$ne' : true}},
                {
                    '$or' :
                        {
                            {'startDate' : {'$type' : {'$ne' : 'date'}}},
                            {'endDate' : {'$type' : {'$ne' : 'date'}}},
                        }
                }
            }
    }
```

But I get error: ***"argument to $type is not a number or a string"***. How can I get desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$type` and `$ne` are the wrong way round. Try something like this:

```
{
  $and: [
    { deleted: { $ne: true } },
    {
      $or: [
        { startDate: { $not: { $type: "date" } } },
        { endDate: { $not: { $type: "date" } } }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

I've changed the order of `$type` and `$ne` and changed `$ne` to `$not`. I've also swapped out the objects for arrays in your `$and` and `$or` queries.

Comment: I'm tried use query it in PHP, and changed all square brackets to braces before placed my code here ;) Thanks, the changing order of $type and $ne, and the changing $ne to $not realy helped me.